# Android JSON library without checked exceptions

Tags: java, json

I've been using org.json.* but I'd very much appreciate NOT dealing with "checked exceptions". Any recommendations?

Comment: Checked exceptions are the reality in Java. The best you can do is find a good idiom to propagate them without too much noise. Consider the "sneaky throw" idiom.

Comment: Try [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).